# How to position div element to exact point on the background

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image

I'm looking for a solution how to position a div to exact position on background. I have a background image ( http://www.jewelryplatform.com/coming-soon.jpg ) and I need to position whole div with form, etc. on the center of the image where you can see the box for that. Second problem that the image will be resizing with windows size. Is there any easy way how to do that?

Comment: Please show the relevant HTML + CCS you have for this layout.

Comment: This is possible using percentages. You can set the background width to 100% and then center the div also using percentages.

Comment: @Teemu: HTML so far is on the site http://www.jewelryplatform.com/.

Comment: @SkyOut: I was able to do horizontal centering with percentages. For vertical it didn't worked with resizing the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you have much experience with css and media queries?

You can add breakpoints in your css and then assign specific style to an element at that breakpoint.

```
#formDiv{ position: absolute; left 50%; top:50%}
@media only screen and (max-width: 995px) {
   #formDiv{ position: absolute; left 25%; top:25%}
}
```

Comment: I wasn't able to do it with the percents. I had to do it for different resolutions. So this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MBK3h/) that will keep a form over the center of a div.

The key is to do `left: 50%` for the form that will center it, and then negatively margin-left half its width to keep it center. The same applies for the `top: 50%`. Because everything is positioned using percentages it will move when you resize the box.

As mentioned in the previous response, you can also use media queries to resize the size of the form at different resolutions as well.

**UPDATE**

Also you can consider resizing the background image when the screen size changes. This can be achieved by setting the `background-size` property with again 100%. [Here](http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-background-size-property/) is a great resource for how to use it